# Source a vimrc from a webpage?

Tags: bash, vim, vimrc

I work with lots of different servers and would like to unify my vimrc across them all. I see that vim has the source command, which I'm assuming works similar to bash. In bash, to source a file from a webpage you go

```
. <(curl -s domain.com)
```

How can I do this with vim? I'm aware that I can instead apply each vim setting by adding an alias like so:

```
alias vim="vim +'colorscheme elflord'"
```

but I'd rather not pass thru all my settings like that. I don't want to have to create a file on the local server I'm on, hence the desire to instead source into the local session. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: That's really weird. I'm absolutely certain `$ vim -u http://foo.bar/myvimrc` worked before. I've used that method countless times but I can't make it work right now.

Comment: @romainl: Replace `-u` with `-S`; the netrw plugin first needs to be loaded (and it only triggers on `:source`).

Comment: @IngoKarkat THAT'S IT I LOVE YOU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim ships with the *netrw plugin*, which enables transparent access of web (or SSH / FTP / etc.) resources, even for `:source`.

```
$ vim -S http://foo.bar/myvimrc
```

Note: You cannot use `vim -u ...`, because the netrw plugin first needs to be loaded, and plugin loading only comes *after* processing of the `~/.vimrc`. Unless you reconfigure the built-in / any locally installed plugins, this change of ordering shouldn't matter.